# awk pivot table and use header row in a repeating column

Tags: awk

I have a table like this:

```
type   heart   muscle   pancreas
A      3       2        2
B      2       2        1
C      6       4        9
```

and would like to pivot it using awk to:

```
A      heart     3
A      muscle    2
A      pancreas  2
B      heart     2
B      muscle    2
B      pancreas  1
C      heart     6
C      muscle    4
C      pancreas  9
```

Firstly I imagine I would have to store the fields of the first input row into an array which would be used to output the second field for each row. Next a while loop that outputs the same first field per row until it reaches the end of the fields in the input row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a scalable, minimal, POSIX Awk solution:

```
awk 'NR==1 {split($0, a); next} {for(f=2;f<=NF;f++) print $1, a[f], $f}' file
```

You can use as many columns and rows as needed.

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` may do:

```
awk '{for (i=2;i<=4;i++) if(NR==1) a[i]=$i; else print $1,a[i],$i}' file
A heart 3
A muscle 2
A pancreas 2
B heart 2
B muscle 2
B pancreas 1
C heart 6
C muscle 4
C pancreas 9
```